# not able to pass dynamic div id by for loop

Tags: javascript, input, prototypejs

i have dynamic id that are store in input field when i tried to `res[i]` it will give me error.i tried by javascript but no success. getting this error

```
TypeError: $(...) is null


newprice = $("#"+res[i]).value();
```

form input

```
<input type="hidden" id="customprice" value="select_91,select_92,select_93" />




    <select  id="select_91" ><option value="">-- Vælg venligst --</option><option value="287" price="0" >1 pose  </option><option value="288" price="50" selected>2 poser  +DKK 50,00</option></select> 

<select  id="select_92" ><option value="">-- Vælg venligst --</option><option value="287" price="0" >1 pose  </option><option value="288" price="50" selected>2 poser  +DKK 50,00</option></select>  

<select  id="select_93" ><option value="">-- Vælg venligst --</option><option value="287" price="0" >1 pose  </option><option value="288" price="50" selected>2 poser  +DKK 50,00</option></select>
```

my code is

```
customprice = $('customprice').value;
res = customprice.split(",");
price = 0;
alert(res.length);
for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    alert(res[i]);
     newprice = $("#"+res[i]).value();
    price = price + parseFloat(newprice);
}
```

Comment: `$('customprice').value` - this is invalid. What is `customprice`? ID, Class?

Comment: @ShaunakD I think it is `protoype` or `mootools`

Comment: i got the id the problem with this $(res[i])

Comment: What is "this" on this.selectedIndex?

Comment: newprice = $("#"+res[i]).options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('price');

Comment: does this help in any case?

Comment: @Swaprks no luck with that

Comment: yes the code is inside the function an i get alert() too of select_91 but no passed into ids

Comment: Try changing `customprice = $('customprice').value;`  to `customprice = $('#customprice').value;`   since customprice is the ID of the hidden input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is PrototypeJS then your error is the `$('#<elementid>')`, as the `$()` method takes an id not a CSS selector.

So **IF** this is PrototypeJS heres how to fix your problem and improve/simplify it a bit as well

Given your HTML above

```
customprice = $('customprice').value;
res = customprice.split(",");
price = 0;

res.each(function(item){
    price += parseFloat($F(item));
});
```

You could also chain these together like this

```
var price = 0;
$F('customprice').split(',').each(function(item){
    price += parseFloat($F(item));
});
```

** The `$F()` method returns the value of the passed id so essentially

`$('<elementid>').value === $F('<elementid>')`

**EDIT**

to get the price attribute of the selected option element

```
var price = 0;
$F('customprice').split(',').each(function(item){

    var optionprice = $(item).options[$(item).selectedIndex].readAttribute('price');

    price += parseFloat(optionprice);

    //this way might also work but the above will work
    var option1price = $(item).down('option[selected]').readAttribute('price');


});
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i want the price attribute not value can you help me with that

Comment: you need the price attribute of the selected option correct?

Comment: see edits to answer above - that should get what you are looking for